# can not add a onClick event in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in reactjs. I'm trying to add a onClick event in my child component like:

```
## BlogList.js
<button onClick={handleDelete(blog.id)}>delete</button>
```

the handleDelete function in the parent component is:

```
## Home.js
    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newBlogs = blogs.filter((blog) => blog.id !== id)
        setBlogs(newBlogs)
    }
```

The error message is:
Cannot update a component (`Home`) while rendering a different component (`BlogList`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `BlogList`

Why didn't it work? Why did it have to write like `<button onClick={()=>handleDelete(blog.id)}>delete</button>` ?

Comment: You can pass it like `onClick={handleDelete}` in-case you don't want to pass any params. But if you want to pass in params inside the function you have to use that syntax `onClick={()=>handleDelete(blog.id)}`. On the first approach I mentioned you are simply passing in all the events associated with that button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onClick={handleDelete(blog.id)}>delete</button>
```

The above code means you execute the function right away after JSX renderings.

You can check the below code to understand immediate function execution

```js
function handleDelete(id) {
  console.log('Executed handleDelete')
}

handleDelete() //executed immediately with `()`!
```

To avoid that case, you should remove `()` like below

```js
function handleDelete(id) {
  console.log('Executed handleDelete')
}

handleDelete //nothing happens!
```

Similarly, in React, you can avoid that case by introduce a wrapper

```js
function handleDelete(id) {
  console.log('Executed handleDelete')
}

const onClick = () => handleDelete(1)
```

And then call it's like below

```
//logic
function handleDelete(id) {
   console.log('Executed handleDelete')
}

const onClick = () => handleDelete(1)

...

//JSX

<button onClick={onClick}>delete</button>
```